# Flowplayer Secure Streaming (via PHP): MP4 videos not Pseudo-Streaming (FLVs do)

Tags: streaming, mp4, flowplayer, pseudo-streaming

I've ran into a problem with MP4 secure pseudo streaming.

First of all, a couple of FACTS for you to get the idea:

- I'm using Flowplayer
- I have mod_h264_streaming installed and working.
- I have successfully added secure streaming plugin (PHP validation) and it's working with pseudo for FLV videos (thanks to mod_h264_streamin, of course).
- I'm testing with an MP4 with the moov-atom at the beginning (and the video starts immediately. No pseudo, though).

Now... when flowplayer loads an MP4, the player makes a request like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/videos/fa3...[security_hash]...46/video.mp4?start=0
```

Note the **?start=0**

When I seek to another part of the video (not yet loaded), the player makes this request:

```
http://mydomain.com/videos/fa3...[security_hash]...46/video.mp4?start=33.342
```

Note the **?start=33.342**

This results in the video starting again from the beginning, which is the problem.

ADDITIONAL FACT: for MP4 files *start* is sent (to the PHP script) as the seconds of the timeline where you click on, and for FLVs *start* is sent as the seek position in Bytes and I think this difference is the main reason of the issue.

**My question is:**

How do I handle, in my PHP pseudo streaming script, MP4 videos streaming?

**Auto-question:** Should I use *byte ranges* headers?

I'm not posting code, as it's not a coding problem, but a conceptual one: let's focus on the idea by now.
Also, all files I'm testing with are well encoded and they are not the problem.

Thanks